# How to stream videos from PC to TV

Tags: applications, audio, video-streaming, android-mini-pc, android-pc

I have a PC with videos, an android mobile device and a TV.
I would like to use my mobile in order to stream videos from my PC to the TV.

Is the a way to do it?

The best offers I found out so far are:

1. connect my TV to "[Rikomagic MK802 mini PC](http://www.rikomagic.co.uk/)", install BSPlayer on
   it and control the Rikomagic from my mobile.
2. Jailbreak AppleTV and use "[Remote for Apple TV](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=develapp.android.atvremote&hl=en)" app

I saw many discussions around this issue but couldn't find the right solution for me.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a Roku that is hooked up to my TV.  I use PLEX to handle streaming videos from my PC and other devices.

Rokus are pretty cheap and PLEX has done what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend giving [BubbleUPnP](http://www.appbrain.com/app/bubbleupnp-upnp-dlna/com.bubblesoft.android.bubbleupnp) a try. You will need a DLNA/UPnP server on your PC for that, but there are plenty of alternatives available. Then you can use *BubbleUPnP* as DLNA server and control point. I use it to tell my TV what video to play (TV acts as renderer then, and can be selected from within BubbleUPnP). You can also tell the TV to play media from your Android device, of course – either from BubbleUPnP (as control point), or from your TV browsing it.

Note, however, that for this to work, it has some pre-conditions:

- your TV must support DLNA (and ideally act as a media renderer)
- you need a DLNA/UPnP server software on your PC (if you're on Windows, I've heard *Media Player* should do)

Answer (score 0):

Does your phone have a [MHL connector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_High-Definition_Link)? If so, you could get a MHL to HDMI adapter, connect the phone to the TV and use a video player to stream the content from the PC.

I'd recommend using [Plex Media Server](https://plex.tv/downloads) on the PC to host the content and the [Plex](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.plexapp.android) Android app to play them. This way you don't have to deal with different video formats as they're automatically transcoded if the source file isn't compatible with Android.

Note that Plex supports streaming for many different devices, so depending on your TV you may be able to stream directly to it.

Comment: I can buy such a connector, but what I'm looking for is a behavior more like the Apple TV where I can control my Media center from my mobile to stream content from my PC

Comment: I have an AppleTV but I still have to use Plex to stream the content. Since I have a third-generation un-jailbreakable AppleTV, I use [PlexConnect](https://github.com/iBaa/PlexConnect) to stream the content. To control the aTV from Android, I think you still need a jailbreakable aTV. You could also use the Rikomagic to run Plex on Android, but I'm not sure about the remote control possibilities of this combo.

Answer (score -2):

Quick'n'dirty, stream content to phone and cast screen to tv.

Try the allcast app.